# How to run Tensorboard from python scipt in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, tensorboard

Tensorboard should be started from commnad line like that:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path
```

I need to run it from code. Until now I use this:

```
import os
os.system('tensorboard --logdir=' + path)
```

However tensorboard do not start because is not included in the system path. I use PyCharm with virtualenv on windows. I don't want to change system paths so the only option is to run it from virtualenv. How to do this?

Answer (score 35):

Using Tensorboard 2 API (2019):

```
from tensorboard import program

tracking_address = log_path # the path of your log file.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tb = program.TensorBoard()
    tb.configure(argv=[None, '--logdir', tracking_address])
    url = tb.launch()
    print(f"Tensorflow listening on {url}")
```

Note: tb.launch() create a daemon thread that will die automatically when your process is finished

Comment: Any idea on how to suppress/redirect the output so it doesn't show in stdout?

Comment: Import tensorflow, the try the following, before calling tensorboard launch: `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)`

Comment: Added in a solution for STDOUT suppression below.

Answer (score 11):

Probably a bit late for an answer, but this is what worked for me in Python 3.6.2:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorboard import main as tb
tf.flags.FLAGS.logdir = "/path/to/graphs/"
tb.main()
```

That runs tensorboard with the default configuration and looks for graphs and summaries in "/path/to/graphs/". You can of course change the log directory and set as many variables as you like using:

```
tf.flags.FLAGS.variable = value
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Currently (tb version 1.10.0, tf version 1.9.0), setting flags in this way throws `UnrecognizedFlagError`. If I set them by calling `.DEFINE_string(...)` first, tb still does not see them and fails with `ValueError: A logdir or db must be specified.`. Isn't there a "valid" way to call tb from python?

Comment: @WunschPunsch I'm using tb 1.9 and tf 1.9 and it still works. I don't know if something changed on version 1.10. However, make sure you run `from tensorboard import main as tb` **before** `tf.flags.FLAGS.logdir = "/path/to/graphs/"`.

Comment: If this answer doesn't work for you, please check out my answer for TensorBoard 1.9 and above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732122/2650622

Comment: Not working. See this answer (11.10.18): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52295534/5470144

Comment: Any updates for Tensorboard 2.6.0?

Answer (score 10):

You should launch `tensorBoard` in the separate thread:

```
def launchTensorBoard():
    import os
    os.system('tensorboard --logdir=' + tensorBoardPath)
    return

import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=launchTensorBoard, args=([]))
t.start()
```

Comment: this doesn't work in an environment because `os.system` has not activated the specific env name (at least for Windows this doesn't work anyway)

Comment: Due to the global interpreter lock, I'd use multiprocessing instead of threading, to reduce unnecessary resource (CPU & memory) sharing and synchronization overhead. The tensorboard loads its info from the disk, with no communication with the running process - so parallelism in this way is redundant.

Answer (score 10):

As I get the same problem, you can use this lines inspired by `tensorboard\main.py`:

```
from tensorboard import default
from tensorboard import program

tb = program.TensorBoard(default.PLUGIN_LOADERS, default.get_assets_zip_provider())
tb.configure(argv=['--logdir', my_directory])
tb.main()
```

With `my_directory` as the folder you want to check. Don't forget to create a separate Thread if you want to avoid to be block after `tb.main()`.
Best regards

EDIT Tensorboard V1.10:

*For some personnal reasons, I write it in a different way:*

```
class TensorBoardTool:

    def __init__(self, dir_path):
        self.dir_path = dir_path

    def run(self):
        # Remove http messages
        log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
        log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        # Start tensorboard server
        tb = program.TensorBoard(default.PLUGIN_LOADERS, default.get_assets_zip_provider())
        tb.configure(argv=['--logdir', self.dir_path])
        url = tb.launch()
        sys.stdout.write('TensorBoard at %s \n' % url)
```

EDIT Tensorboard V1.12:

*According to Elad Weiss and tsbertalan for the version 1.12 of tensorboard.*

```
    def run(self):
        # Remove http messages
        log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        # Start tensorboard server
        tb = program.TensorBoard(default.get_plugins(), default.get_assets_zip_provider())
        tb.configure(argv=[None, '--logdir', self.dir_path])
        url = tb.launch()
        sys.stdout.write('TensorBoard at %s \n' % url)
```

Then to run it just do:

```
# Tensorboard tool launch
tb_tool = TensorBoardTool(work_dir)
tb_tool.run()
```

This will allow you to run a Tensorboard server at same time as your main process, without disturbing http request!

Comment: This is the only answer that almost works (11.10.18). You need to change however to `tb.configure(argv=[None, '--logdir', my_directory])` because new tensorboard starts parsing at argv[1:]

Comment: Additionally, I changed the arguments to `program.TensorBoard` to `plugins=default.get_plugins(), assets_zip_provider=default.get_assets_zip_provider()`.

Comment: I also used a `logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)` to suppress verbose INFO output from tensorboard.

Answer (score 9):

For Tensorboard 2.1.0, this works for me:

```sh
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir $PWD/logs
```

You must have your env active first. (In my case, `conda install` had a fatal error, so I needed to reinstall `tf` via `pip` inside `conda`.)

Answer (score 5):

A full solution for Tensorboard 2 (2019), with automatic opening of the Chrome browser, for Windows and Linux. Works for both environments: conda and virtualenv. **This solution suppresses the Tensorboard output so it doesn't (irritatingly) show in stdout**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
import os

class TensorboardSupervisor:
    def __init__(self, log_dp):
            self.server = TensorboardServer(log_dp)
            self.server.start()
            print("Started Tensorboard Server")
            self.chrome = ChromeProcess()
            print("Started Chrome Browser")
            self.chrome.start()

    def finalize(self):
        if self.server.is_alive():
            print('Killing Tensorboard Server')
            self.server.terminate()
            self.server.join()
        # As a preference, we leave chrome open - but this may be amended similar to the method above


class TensorboardServer(Process):
    def __init__(self, log_dp):
        super().__init__()
        self.os_name = os.name
        self.log_dp = str(log_dp)
        # self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        if self.os_name == 'nt':  # Windows
            os.system(f'{sys.executable} -m tensorboard.main --logdir "{self.log_dp}" 2> NUL')
        elif self.os_name == 'posix':  # Linux
            os.system(f'{sys.executable} -m tensorboard.main --logdir "{self.log_dp}" '
                      f'--host `hostname -I` >/dev/null 2>&1')
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f'No support for OS : {self.os_name}')
    
    
class ChromeProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.os_name = os.name
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        if self.os_name == 'nt':  # Windows
            os.system(f'start chrome  http://localhost:6006/')
        elif self.os_name == 'posix':  # Linux
            os.system(f'google-chrome http://localhost:6006/')
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f'No support for OS : {self.os_name}')
```

Initialization:

```
tb_sup = TensorboardSupervisor('path/to/logs')
```

After finishing the training/testing:

```
tb_sup.finalize()
```

Comment: For me this method resulted in a deadlock. The main training/testing process won't terminate as the `.join()` method is waiting for the subprocess to stop. As the tensorboard process won't stop on it's own, this will lead to an unresponsive terminal. An easy workaround is to add the lines `self.server.terminate()` and `self.chrome.terminate()` to the `finalize()` method of `TensorboardSupervisor` to explicitely terminate the subprocess such that the main process can end.

Comment: Yep, I totally agree. I've updated the solution as it is in my current code framework - which indeed includes the missing terminate you've just mentioned. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3):

If your python interpreter path is：

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

You can run this command instead of tensorboard

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py
```

Answer (score 2):

To run tensorboard from a python script within a specified virtual environment you have to change `tensorboard` to `/path/to/your/environment/bin/tensorboard`. It is also recommended to execute the command in a separate thread as suggested by @Dmitry.

Together it looks like this and works for me with tb and tf version 1.14.0:

```
def run_tensorboard(logdir_absolute):

   import os, threading
   tb_thread = threading.Thread(
          target=lambda: os.system('/home/username/anaconda3/envs/'
                                   'env_name/bin/tensorboard '
                                   '--logdir=' + logdir_absolute),
          daemon=True)
   tb_thread.start()
```

Comment: Great solution - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of TensorBoard version 1.9.0, the following works to start TensorBoard with default settings in the same Python process:

```
import tensorboard as tb
import tensorboard.program
import tensorboard.default

tb.program.FLAGS.logdir = 'path/to/logdir'
tb.program.main(tb.default.get_plugins(),
                tb.default.get_assets_zip_provider())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will open a Chrome tab and launches TensorBoard. Simply provide the desired directory  and your system's name .

```
import os
os.system(
    "cd <directory> \
    && google-chrome http://<your computer name>:6007 \
    && tensorboard --port=6007 --logdir runs"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Had the same problem:*
As you're working on Windows, you can use batch files to fully-automate opening tensorboard like in the exaple below.

As you probably want to open tensorboard within a visible console window (cmd.exe). Calling one batch-file within your IDE (pycharm) will run it within the IDE, so in the background, which means you can't see the console. Therefore, you can use a workaround: call a batch-file that then calls the batch-file to start tensorboard.

*Note: I'm using [Anaconda](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html) as my virtual-environment for this example*

```
batch_filename = 'start_tb.bat'  # set filename for batch file
tb_command = 'tensorboard --logdir=' + log_dir  # join strings for tensorflow command

# creates batch file that will call seconds batch file in console window (cmd.exe)
with open(os.path.join('invoke.bat'), "w") as f:
    f.writelines('start ' + batch_filename)

# created batch file that activates Anaconda environment and starts tensorboard
with open(os.path.join(batch_filename), "w") as f:
    f.writelines('\nconda activate YOURCondaEnvNAME  && ' + tb_command)  # change to your conda environment, or other virtualenv

# starts tensorboard using the batch files (will open console window)
# calls the 'invoke.bat' that will call 'start_tb.bat'
os.system('invoke.bat')

# starts tensorboard in default browser >> ATTENTION: must be adapted to local host
os.system('start "" http://YOUR-COMPUTER-NAME:6006/')  # just copy the URL that tensorboard runs at on your computer
```

Sometimes you might have to refresh tensorboard within your browser, as it opened already before it was properly set-up.

Answer (score -2):

Try running from python

```
import os
os.system('python -m tensorflow.tensorboard --logdir=' + path)
```

works for me in PyCharm (but on linux, so if the shell syntax is different then you have to tweak it)

Comment: Another way is to tweak environment's variables inside PyCharm environment's settings so as to add path to executable tensorboard to PATH, but posted answer is cleaner and more versatile IMHO