# Tensorboard name logdir is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was installing tensorboard `using pip install tensorboard`. All worked fine

I run my network and the writer also worked fine

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("pathtofolder", sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(h))
    writer.close()
```

now I wanted to see in tensorboard how it learned

I inserted

```
import tensorflow, tensorboard

tensorboard --logdir /pathtofolder
```

and received the error message. 
NameError: name 'logdir' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the command on terminal/cmd.

Open your terminal/cmd and run:

```
tensorboard --logdir ./PATH_TO_THE_EVENT_FILES
```

[image]

If you want to run `Tensorboard` on python file see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158694/how-to-run-tensorboard-from-python-scipt-in-virtualenv/51732122#51732122):

Comment: I have tried it now in the cmd but the same error occurred, can you give the full screenshot? I even tried the link with os.system but it does not know python prompt

Comment: just ```tensorboard --logdir ./``` is matter. Another alternative is ```tensorboard --logdir==./```

Comment: tensorboard could not be found. In what directory are you with the cmd?

Comment: ok I added the text until python main.py --logdir=/path/to/log_file/, then comes that it does not know python, it is wrongly spelled or could not be found.

Comment: Thanks, so now it worked as I didnt use the directionary where tensorflow is, but the directionary where python was!