# Failed to launch tensorboard in vscode with error info "pytorch_profiler:Monitor runs begin"

Tags: visual-studio-code, tensorboard

I'am using tensorboard integration supported by vscode from remote server, after launching tensorboard session, only return a blank TensorBoard window, with no substance see in pic
[tensorboard window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0ibs.png)

I find some error info in the output of python

```
Python interpreter path: /usr/bin/python3
Starting Jedi language server.
> conda --version
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import tensorboard; print(tensorboard.__version__)"
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import tensorboard; print(tensorboard.__version__)"
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import torch_tb_profiler"
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import torch_tb_profiler"
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/pythonFiles/tensorboard_launcher.py ~/HandyRL
Error 2021-05-01 14:56:39: INFO:pytorch_profiler:Monitor runs begin
```

While using `tensorboard --logdir=log --host` works fine

Comment: I too am facing this issue, currently I am using this workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/55708102/11445460.